# How to remove or prevent unexpected __pycache__ files in qemu rpm packaging?

Tags: rpm, qemu, rpm-spec

I am using the fedora qemu.spec file to build qemu rpm package. But I got the error:
[image]
I found there has some `install` instruction about tracetool in qemu.spec file. And there is not any setup about `__pycache__`. What should I do to handle this problem? Any suggestions are welcome. If you need any further information, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

PS:
The complete `qemu.spec` can be found here:  https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/qemu/blob/f33/f/qemu.spec

Comment: This sounds like your RPM build system may be expecting python2 `.pyc` files and not python3 ones. Look for macros calling out python maybe?

Comment: I have tried `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1`. But does not work. Thanks your reply bro. Wish you have a good day.

Comment: This https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Python/#_files_to_include